# How to use twisted pair as console to manage Cisco devices?

Tags: cisco

Is this possible to use a normal twisted pair cable or roll over to manage Cisco devices through console port? (without any converter to USB) I tested before a roll over and connected it to Cisco switch but it didn't worked. is there any kind of software to virtually convert a twisted pair to console?

Answer (score 0):

If line vty is activated you Connect your device to a computer  via ethernet cable and use telnet or ssh to do that